Problem with displaying text and elements in Xamarin Forms on the smartphone and emulator screen
I encountered an issue with Xamarin Forms where not all text is displayed in the label, and elements that are off-screen are not shown. Rotating the smartphone temporarily resolves the issue until the data is reloaded or the application updates the data. This problem occurs both on the emulator and on an actual smartphone, and it happens across different projects.
Display when loading:
enter image description here
Display when changing orientation:
enter image description here
Display when orientation returns:
enter image description here
I have already tried to solve the problem using:

Changing the font size:
Table Label.Font Size = Device.GetNamedSize(Name Size.Small, type of(Label));
Using lineBreakMode:
Table Label.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode.WordWrap;
Setting HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions:
Table Label.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
TableLabel.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

xaml code:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Raspisanie.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Text="ChangingSides" Clicked="ChangingSidesClicked"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <Button Text="Previous table" Clicked="OnPreviousClicked"/>
                    <Button Text="Next table" Clicked="OnNextClicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="TableLabel" Text="The table will be displayed here"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

cs code:
string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
TableLabel.Text = responseData;

cs does not affect the display, because display problems occur when only elements are created

please read [ask] before posting.  Its almost impossible to help you without seeing the relevant code/markup

I tried to add clarity

Method.ForceLayout() in Xamarin.Forms is used to force the layout of an element and its child elements to be updated. When you call this method, it forces the element to go through the layout process again, which can be useful if you have changed the properties of the element that affect its size or location and want the changes to take effect immediately.
Here is a usage example: your View.ForceLayout();
This method can be useful in situations where there is no automatic layout update and you need to manually initiate layout recalculation.
